# Pull through featured image in a custom menu

Tags: wordpress

Trying to pull through the featured image in a custom menu without a plugin so I can style it how I want.

This is the code I have so far;

```
<?php
$navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(6); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
$previousMenuParent = $level = 0;                         
foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {
$level = 0;
echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';                            
echo '<br><br>';
**image goes here**
}
?>
```

I've tried;

```
echo $menu->title = has_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id);         
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id, 'thumbnail') : $menu->title;
echo has_post_thumbnail( $menu->object_id );
```

I feel like i'm so close and one of these will pull the image through, but struggling to get over the line!

Comment: featured image of the currently displayed post? or you have assigned images to menus via some custom plugin?

Comment: @Mohsin featured image of the page itself

Comment: i got it! You can check my answer below, so it will show featured image of linked item from the menu for each item when featured image is set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the id of the post in the loop and then pass that in to `get_the_post_thumbnail`. Check out the code below. Hope it helps!

```
$navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(6); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
$previousMenuParent = $level = 0;                         
foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {
    $level = 0;
    echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';                
    echo '<br><br>';
    $id = $menu->object_id;
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id); 

}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that and still no success which is what I don't understand...

Comment: @Sam I had another look at this and think I found your problem. I'll edit my answer and include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Info you were looking for is in Menu obj's `object_id` property, you can see that by var_dump($menu) see my commented line in the code below.

Object_id gives you resource ID for menu linked Post or Page. Now you can check if that page/post have post thumbnail or not, if success, then you can echo the same.

```
$navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(6); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
    $previousMenuParent = $level = 0;                         
    foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {
        // var_dump($menu);
    $level = 0;
    $post_id = (int)$menu->object_id;
    echo '<li><a href="'. $menu->url .'">'. $menu->title .'</a>';                            
    echo '<br><br>';

    if(has_post_thumbnail( $post_id )){
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
    }

    }
```